# How to change the x-axis in matplotlib without changing the value in title of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame:

```
 index    0     1     2     3     4     5
 1        12    13    14    15    13    12


 df.plot()
```

The x-axis would be in the range from 0-5, but I want to change to 1-6 and do not want to change the columns' title value by `df.columns = df.columns + 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the axes object from `df.plot()` and then modify the x axis tick labels using the function `set_xticklabels()`:

```
ax = df.plot()
ax.set_xticklabels([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

Note that this uses the tick locations that pandas/matplotlib generates automatically.

Comment: Better to use a range rather than writing all the numbers manually